# Inject property into existing List with LINQ

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have a Generic List of objects.  Those objects have 4 properties.  3 are set by LINQ earlier in the app.  Is it possible to insert the 4th property into the existing List using LINQ to SQL without looping through each object in the List?

***EDIT***
For reference sake, one of the first properties is an ID on the record, so I will know with each object in the List what the 4th property should be in the database, but I was hoping to do it without a For Loop as the List might be rather huge.

Comment: Generic List + LINQ to SQL? Are you sure you're not talking about LINQ to Objects here?

Comment: How would you even theoretically do this? You have to look at least look at every ID once, so that's O(n) = foreach/for loop right there.

Comment: I probably am talking about LINQ to Objects, I'm new to this.  I am linking to an method that returns an object from the Entity Framework.

Comment: @BrokenGlass, you are right and as I was explaining this to a coworker I realized the exact same thing.  So this question is irrelevant.

Comment: For future reference, if the object comes from the Entity Framework, you're talking about LINQ-to-Entities. LINQ-to-Objects is when you use regular collections of objects (i.e. IEnumerable<T>).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I 100% understand, but in your LINQ query you could do something like this:

```
var result = from r in Repository
             select new MyType()
             {
                 Value1 = r.Value1,
                 Value2 = r.Value2,
                 Value3 = r.Value3,
                 Value4 = "MyValue",
             }
```

Untested, but the general idea should work.